# Broken comment is un-editable and un-deletable

Tags: support, mathjax, comment

I added a comment to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880637/combinations-of-non-adjacent-number-sequences) with broken MathJax tagging, and it is causing all comments to be formatted horribly *and* putting the "Edit" and delete buttons under the links on the right side of the page, making it impossible to delete the comment.

[image]

I believe it is the second comment that is causing the problem. I can't even flag my own comment :)

Comment: Related maybe?: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13603/formatting-bug-long-mathjax-or-code-blocks-break-entire-post-or-page.

Comment: Definitely, I'd call it a duplicate. @JonasMeyer

Comment: This should really be a flag, on the post if you can't flag the comment. This issue has come up before on meta.

Comment: Thanks, flagged the question. Hadn't considered that :) @ArthurFischer

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: You just missed the very first `$`, and I fixed it instead of deleting it. I hope that's fine.